# Strange cyrus/imaps Logins without valid password

Tags: passwords, email, server, imap

I found apparently successful logins from a foreign ip-address to our cyrus-imap server:

```
Nov 24 08:16:20 server-1 cyrus/imaps[12101]: starttls: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits new) no authentication
Nov 24 08:16:20 server-1 cyrus/imaps[12101]: login: 33.44.55.66.static.example.org [33.44.55.66] example@mx.com PLAIN+TLS User logged in SESSIONID=<cyrus-12101-1266046209-1-18415252315816507673>
```

After changing the saslauthd password for this mailbox, this log entries did not change ("PLAIN+TLS User **logged in** SESSIONID=" persists). My imapd.conf contains:

```
sasl_mech_list: PLAIN
sasl_pwcheck_method: saslauthd
```

The imapd.c source file shows one possibility for login without password (nosaslpasswdcheck=1 when imapd ist started with "-N" parameter) but my cmdline shows "imapd -s -U 30". Is this case a security problem in cyrus-imapd, which allows passwordless logins?